# Invalid android_key parameter - Facebook login

Tags: facebook, authentication, coronasdk

I am trying to use facebook login in my application. The problem is that I am getting the following error:

[image]

My settings are:

[image]

In the begging I tried to use a key that I generate using the java keytool but it didn't work (same error). Then I saw some post here in Stackoverflow and I changed the key to the one that appears on the error, but the problem remains.

**Any idea what I am missing?**

**Does the `=` needed at the end of the key?**

Comment: Yes, the = is needed, but your error is without the =. isn't that the problem?

Comment: @BrunoDomingues finally I solved it, I was using the debug and not the release key, that was the problem